# Jquery each and attr functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html:

```
<input id="testme" test="something"/><label test="something2"></label>
```

and this js

```
$("[test]").each(alert($(this).attr("test")));
```

demoed here:

[jsfidde](http://jsfiddle.net/AARev/)

I would think the alert would give me `"something"` and then `"something2"`. But it does nothing!

What is going on?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are alerting the wrong thing. The `each` simply returns the collection/jQuery. You would need to alert inside the each callback to alert the values of the *custom attribute*. Also. Please use the `data-` prefix when assigning [custom attributes][1] for better standards compliance.

```
$(".classname").each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("classname"));
});
```

Comment: haha. ya sorry about the fugged example. having the alert in the wrong spot was a typo. The issue, as you also demonstrated, was that I was missing `function(){`. And yes, I plan to use `data-`. This is the first time I was going to use `data-` actually, so i took it off when there was a problem thinking that was causing it. But I just made the stupid mistake of forgetting the `function(){` thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) takes a function, it should look like this instead:

```
$("[test]").each(function() {
  alert($(this).attr("test"));
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5dWmV/).