# using jquery to find .each on .attr() with regex

Tags: jquery, regex, each

I am sure this has been answered before, but I cant find the correct search terms.

I would like to use jquery[1.3.2] .each() function to search an object for a set name+var(i) `info1="value1", info2="value2"` the (i) val is unknown for the function, could be 0+n

I am parsing the id to the function, so my questions are

```
function findInfos(hostId){
 $($('#'+hostId).attr('[info]')).each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('[info(i)]'));
    });
 }
```

1. How would I insert the (i)
2. Is it possible to do a search on a partial regex instead of using (i), (info*) `infoA, infoB`
3. given the object ID will be passed to the function and unknown what is the correct structure use of .each()

I did take a look at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606133/jquery-each-and-attr-functions` but could not figure out how to limit the .each() to the passed ID.

thx Art

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're looking at a single element with multiple attributes, and you want to do something with the attributes that match a certain regex, like `/^info\d$/`. If so, what you want to do is cycle through the DOM element's `attributes` `NamedNodeMap`:

```
​var el = $('#foo');
var attributes = el[0].attributes;

$.each(attributes,function(i,attr){
    var name = attr.nodeName;
    var val = attr.nodeValue;
    var regex = /^info\d$/;

    if(name.match(regex)) {
        //Do something with your matched attributes
    }
});​
```

Tested with jQuery 1.3.2

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/gcbqW/)

Comment: @artvanderlay just a note that the regex in my example will only match "info0" through "info9". I assume you can alter the regex to suit your needs.

Comment: as an interesting side effect, it seems to be iterating through the attributes backwards, with the exception of width/height that come first. `<id="foo" i1="a" i2="b" i3="c" />` it will show c,b,a, is it possible to make it iterate fwd through the attributes? so it outputs a,b,c. thx Art

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, I believe you want something like this:

```
function findInfos(hostId) {
    $('#' + hostId).attr('[info]').each(function(i) {
        alert($(this).attr('[info'+i+']'));
    });
}​
```

Also, avoid assigning the same id to multiple objects, as this can result in some *nasty* errors.

Comment: This answer ignores the fact that `$(hostId).attr('[info'])` is not a valid way to get a list of attributes that contain the word "info". There's also a stray `)` in there that would prevent this code from executing in the first place

Comment: @Elliot Bonneville thx for the assist, but still could not get it to work, however jackwanders will do the trick