# jquery or javascript to sort attributes of a html object before regex

Tags: jquery, html, regex, sorting

as a follow on from a previous question [using jquery to find .each on .attr() with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363585/using-jquery-to-find-each-on-attr-with-regex/11363790#comment14984726_11363790),

I would like to sort the attributes alphabetically before running them through .each(). The final output is to add child divs in order of the attributes.

```
<div id="myElement" extra1="a" stuff="z" extra9="c" more="y" extra5="b" /div>
```

when I parse it through the code below, it outputs values `b,c,a`, what i need is to sort the elements first into order `extra1, extra5, extra9, more, stuff` then run it through the .each()+regex so the values come out as `a,b,c`

```
var el = $('#myElement');
var attributes = el[0].attributes;

$.each(attributes,function(i,attr){
var name = attr.nodeName;
var val = attr.nodeValue;
var regex = /^extra\d$/;

  if(name.match(regex)) {
    $(parentDiv).append("<div id="+val+" /div>");
  }
});​
```

thx in advance Art

Answer (score 2):

Per [this MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.attributes), the attributes collection is a map, not an array so it does not have a defined order.  If you wanted it sorted, you would first have to put it in array, sort that and then do `.each()` on the sorted array.

Or, you could collect the results in your `.each()` into an array, sort those results and then append the sorted results in the desired order at the end.  Looking at your code, I think that is less work so you could do that like this:

```
var el = $('#myElement');
var attributes = el[0].attributes;
var output = [];

$.each(attributes,function(i,attr){
    var name = attr.nodeName;
    var val = attr.nodeValue;
    var regex = /^extra\d$/;

    if(name.match(regex)) {
        output.push("<div id="+val+" /div>");
    }
});​
$(parentDiv).append(output.sort().join(""));
```

This simple sort works if your attributes can be sorted into lexigraphic order and you don't go beyond `extra9`.  If it goes beyond that single digit number, then you'll have to convert the digits to numbers and use a custom sort function to generate the right sort order like this:

```
var el = $('#myElement');
var attributes = el[0].attributes;
var output = [];
var regex = /^extra(\d+)$/;

$.each(attributes,function(i,attr){
    var name = attr.nodeName;
    var val = attr.nodeValue;
    var matches, item;

    if(matches = name.match(regex)) {
        item = {};
        item.html = "<div id="+val+" /div>";
        item.num = parseInt(matches[1], 10);
        output.push(item);
    }
});​
// sort array of objects with a custom sort function
output.sort(function(a, b) {
    return(a.num - b.num);
});
// append data in correct order now that the items are sorted
for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    $(parentDiv).append(output[i].html);
}
```